# Convert a Time Value Expressed as a String to Minutes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to convert string values expressed in hours and minutes -- for example, the values I'm working with are strings like so: "1:30" or "00:45" -- into minutes in JavaScript. I've seen plenty of examples going the other way, but haven't found any solutions for this particular question, where you go from a string value in this "0.00" string format to minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Date()` object and the `getMinutes()` function.  Since you only care about a time, you'll need to initialize the object with a dummy date...

```js
var time = "01:45";
var d = new Date("2000-01-01 " + time + ":00");
var minutes = d.getMinutes() + (d.getHours() * 60);
console.log(minutes.toString());
```

Comment: But if you enter in "01:45" this is going to give you 45, which is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it's 45 + 60*hours?  I must have misinterpreted your question, let me try again....

Comment: Hey, Muirik: Do you mean like this above?  I'm not sure what you mean by *in this "0.00" string format*.  Hopefully the above is right?